# In which situations we make variables as public and methods as private?

Tags: java, c++, oop

Currently I am learning basics of java and C++. I have read in book **Let Us C++**, that in almost every case we we make instance variables private and methods public for the security purposes. But it is also mentioned in this book that in some cases we make variables public and methods private..

I am continuously thinking, in which cases we will do so. Can anyone please explain this.

Comment: You can always have need for a utility function in a class that your users shouldn't care less about. It's great if you take a strict functions do one thing approach.

Comment: @chris, sir can u please give any example for the same.

Comment: If you do a singleton in C++ the constructor will be in private

Comment: Please improve quality of your posts (spelling, punctuation, big letters at the beginning of sentence etc.).

Comment: @Spook, thanks, I will remember this from next time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private methods (or private member functions in C++ terminology) are mostly useful as helper functions. For example, think of the case that you want to implement fractions, but want to ensure that your fraction is always normalized. Then you could use a private member function `normalize()` which normalizes your fraction, and which is called after each operation which might result in a non-normalized fraction, for example (C++ code):

```
class Fraction
{
public:
  Fraction(int num, int den = 1);
  Fraction operator+=(Fraction const& other);
  Fraction operator*=(Fraction const& other);
  // ...
private:
  int numerator, denominator;
};

Fraction::Fraction(int num, int den):
  numerator(num),
  denominator(den)
{
  normalize();
}

Fraction Fraction::operator+=(Fraction const& other)
{
  int new_den = denominator*other.denominator;
  numerator = numerator*other.denominator + denominator*other.numerator;
  denominator = new_den;
}

Fraction Fraction::operator*=(Fraction const& other)
{
  numerator *= other.numerator;
  denominator *= other.denominator;
  normalize();
}

void Fraction::normalize()
{
  int factor = gcd(numerator, denominator);
  numerator /= factor;
  denominator /= factor;
}
```

Another, C++ specific use of private functions is based on the fact that in C++ private is only about access control, not about visibility. This enables to do unoverridable pre-post-condition checking in the base class while making the actual function virtual:

```
class Base
{
public:
  foo frobnicate(some arguments);
private:
  virtual foo do_frobnicate(some arguments) = 0;
};

foo Base::frobnicate(some arguments)
{
  check_precondition(arguments);
  foo result = do_frobnicate(arguments);
  check_post_condition(foo);
  return foo;
}
```

Classes derived from `Base` will override `do_frobnicate`, while users will call `frobnicate` which always checks the pre/postconditions no matter what the derived class does.

Comment: What about making a variable public? Any reason to do so?

Comment: @petric My general rule is that either all of the variables are public (a struct), or none are.  In the first case, I may add constructors for convenience (in C++03, anyway---in C++11, the unified initialization syntax largely eliminates the need), and I guess it's possible that I might want a private function for use by these constructors (although it's certainly not very frequent).

Answer (score 2):

Generally static final variables are public in a class. If you don't need to change the value of that variable and want other classes to access it then you make it public static final.

Private methods are used only within the class for doing the task, which is internal to that class. Like a utility method or some business calculation method. Or simply to break the code of public method into multiple private methods, so that methods don't grow too big.

Answer (score 1):

When a method is to be used by other methods(public) of the class and you do not want the object to access that method directly, we make that method as private.

And in some cases, if you want to access your variable directly from the class object, then make it public.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the varibale or methode in other classes don't make it public. This goes for methodes and variables.

Answer (score 1):

private methods are for the internal use of the class. They can be called from other public classes. Those are private because you encapsualted from outer world.

For example

```
public void method1(){
    method2();
}

private void method2(){
    // for internal use
}
```

Public variables are mainly used for class variables in which cases there is no harm of direct accessing the variables from outside. For example

```
public static  final int FLAG = true;
```

You can directly call the variable from outside.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how much security you want for each class.

For example, if you have a Vector class, that only has 3 variables x, y and z, you should make them public. Many classes will probably use the Vector class and it's fine if they change values in it.

If you have a Person class that stores credit card number, background record, address etc, you should make them private to avoid security issues.

However, if you have all variables as private, and you provide accessors and mutators for all of them, you're effectively making them just like public (but with more work).

EDIT:
All constant variables should be public, because you cannot change them anyway.
Static variables could be both, depending on a situation. Probably better to have static get and set functions for static variables.

Comment: There is no reason for all constant variables to be public. They could be an implementation detail with no reason to be public at all.

Comment: No reason to be private either! Why hide something you can't change?

Comment: The whole point is to avoid security issues. No issue - no need for private keyword.

Comment: No, that is no the whole point at all. Why make public something the client does not need?

Comment: @ole_92 The point of access specifiers is definitely not restricted to security, and depending on the definition of security, it's woefully inadequate for that purpose anyway. Access specifiers also provides better encapsulation, by clearly documenting what the public interface is.

Comment: @juanchopanza Why make private something that cannot be changed? Unless I want to specifically restrict other classes from viewing the constant, why would I hide it?

Comment: @Cong Xu How do private constants provide better encapsulation? Again, unless other classes should not be allowed to view the constant, I cannot think of one reason why make it private.

Comment: Why make public something that does not need to be public? It is a basic principle of OOP.

Comment: @ole_92 not directly, but they help encapsulation by clearly telling readers that they are not part of the public interface. If people see a public constant, it is not immediately clear whether they should be concerned about it or if it's an implementation detail. [There are reasons why things are private by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532107/why-data-members-are-private-by-default-in-c) in C++ and Java.

Answer (score 1):

Private variables or functions can be use only in the class where they are declarated.

Public variables or functions can be use everywhere in your application.

So you should declarate private all those variables and functions that you are going to use **ONLY** in the class where they belong.

Example:

```
public class Car {
    private String model;

    public setModel(String model) {
        if (model != null)
            this.model = model;
    }

    public getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    private doSomething() {
        model = "Ford";
    }
}
```

In the class Car we declarate the String model as private because we are going to use it only in the class Car, doing this we assure that other classes couldn't change the value of this String without using the function setModel.

The functions setModel and getModel are public, so we can access the private variable model from other classes ONLY using those methods.

In this example, the function setModel checks if the value its null, in which case it doesn't set the value. Here you can see that if you had declarated the String model as public, you wouldn't have control over what value it's being recorded.

The function doSomething is private and other classes can't use it. For other side, like this function is private and it belong to the same class where is the String model, it can change its value without using the method setModel.

Answer (score 1):

A rule of thumb, you make methods  `public` when it is okay for other classes to access them.  internal methods or helper methods should either be `protected` or `private`.`Protected` if you want the method to be extendable by those extending your class however if you don't want this just mark them `private`.